# How To add ng-model to ChoiceType symfony?

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I need to add an ng-model to every choice in my choice list, so I could watch each choice in angularjs.
This is my ChoiceType. I tried adding an attr but it only added it, to the whole list not every choice in the list, I also tried adding a choice_attr but it didn't work.

```
->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'   => Type::getChoices(),
            'multiple'  =>false,
            'expanded'  =>true,
        ])
```

This is my twig file.

```
  <div ng-controller="CreditServiceController">
    {{ form_row(form.type) }}
```

and this is my angular js.

```
app.controller('CreditServiceController', function ($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.serviceType = "";

$scope.$watch('serviceType', function () {
    console.log('hello');
})
```

Comment: Use the [`choice_attr`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr).  `'choice_attr' => ['ng-model' => 'pDescription']`

Comment: I've already tried it, but it's not working. I don't know why.

Comment: You said you tried `attr`, `choice_attr` is different. Otherwise show us your view for the form, which may be conflicting.

Comment: or try using `'choice_attr' => function() { return ['ng-model' => 'pDescription']; },`

Comment: Now, it's working. Thank you.